# Консольная команда с токеном

Tags: yii2, yii, github, установка, token

Смотрел https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tme8P5JbdSw&list=PL9XdPIVgBVVmYWGF3BFZwHu4Fz9fa6GJd&index=3&t=0s .
С 10:15 по 12:10 речь зашла о токенах. Скажите какова консольная команда (о которой шла речь на 12:10), содержащая токен.

Comment: Стоит инофрмацию из видео перенести текстом в вопрос. Гугл может в любой момент удалить автора видео/само видео и вопрос сразу потеряет всю информацию.

Comment: Там же всё понятно показано... Хотя и подозрительно.